# Как установить количество столбцов в QGridLayout?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator

Как указать количество столбцов QGridLayout?

Answer (score 3):

При добавлении элементов, ты указываешь, в какой колонке он будет находиться.

```
void addWidget(QWidget *, int row, int column, Qt::Alignment = Qt::Alignment());
```

Если тебе нужны пустые колонки, то можно сделать так:

```
layout->addWidget(new MyWidget, 0, 2);  // виджет в третьей колонке
layout->setColumnStretcn(0, 1);         // пустая колонка 1
layout->setColumnStretcn(1, 1);         // пустая колонка 2
layout->setColumnStretcn(2, 1);         // колонка 3, там где находится виджет
```